# Request Google Analytics access of third party

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How can I request the permission to read and analyse the Google analytics data of the third party.

Use case is, I may give a link to the third party, when they click, it will ask for granting permission to share their Google Analytics Data to me. After they've granted I could get their Google Analytics data.

I have created a Project from which I used to get GA data by using GA Reporting API v4

Comment: Here you can find how an application authorizes requests to the Analytics Reporting API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization

Comment: Thanks, I was also wondering if there is a comprehensive guide.